# Implementing a text-based fallback for pygtk applications

Tags: python, pygtk

I have a pygtk application and would like to provide a text-based fallback mode for it. When mporting gtk without a X display available I see only a GtkWarning on stderr but no exception I could take advantage of and checking for DISPLAY seems like an ugly hack. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking `gtk.gdk.screen_get_default()` does it, however there seems no way to suppress the GTK warnings.